# Generating entities from tables from two different schemas with JPA 2.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, database-schema

I'm currently trying to figure out how to work with two different schemas on my project: currently I can successfully generate my entities from two different Datasources that I created on Eclipse

[image: Database Connection]

Basically it's the same server, but I am forced to use two different connection strings in order to access both schemas.
The problem is that by switching connection in order to generate the entities from the other schema, the previous entities cannot be recognized:
[image: Entities not recognized]

Is there a way to solve this problem? Is there a way for me to make my entities recognized no matter what?

EDIT:
I ended up creating 2 additional JPA projects where I generate my entities, then I added those 2 projects into the main project's POM but still it only reads one persistence unit and the entities coming from the other schema are not recognized.

Comment: Have you tried schema attribute inside @Table

Comment: I did, it just doesn't work, it just says there is no schema called like that

Comment: `orm.xml` allows specification of schema info in a separate file, rather than hardcoding in java classes

Comment: I currently do not seem to find this file, do I need to configure it by myself?

Comment: It won't magically appear out of air. As any JPA docs would tell you, you create it yourself if you want to specify some mapping info in XML rather than annotations (or to supplement annotations), and then specify it in `persistence.xml`. http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/metadata_xml.html

Comment: I'm sorry but I still can't really understand how to be sure that I can generate entities from multiple schemas withouth this problem occurring: I specified the `orm.xml` and added it to my `persistence.xml`, but I still get the same error, I also tried to add multiple `persistence-units` but to no avail.

Comment: You want to generate 2 different schema from entities or Entities from 2 different schema ? I am sorry but I bit confused from your question.

Comment: I want to generate Entities from 2 different schemas(on MySQL)

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you, this is confusing for me too, I'm still here trying to figure out how to generate Entities from two different schemas(and to also be able to use BOTH Entities generated with JPA tools, because atm I can't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to answer this question, I finally found a solution for this issue.
In the `application.properties` we added the properties for the schemas `modules` and `supplychain`, and I created 2 JPA projects for both schemas, and generated the entities there.
After that, we created the beans in the SpringServletInitializer:

```
    private Map<String, String> jpaProperties() {

    Map<String, String> p = new HashMap<String, String>();

    p.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
    p.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings",
            env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings"));
    p.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql"));
    p.put("hibernate.naming.physical-strategy", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy"));
    p.put("hibernate.ddl-auto", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));

    return p;
}



@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "modules.datasource")
public DataSource modulesDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "supplychain.datasource")
public DataSource supplychainDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name="modules")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean modulesEntityManagerFactory(
        org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) throws IOException {
    return builder.dataSource(modulesDataSource()).packages(Moduli.class).properties(jpaProperties()).persistenceUnit("JPAModules").build();
}

@Bean(name="supplychain")
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean supplychainEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder)
        throws IOException {
    return builder.dataSource(supplychainDataSource()).packages(Rent.class).properties(jpaProperties()).persistenceUnit("JPASupplychain").build();
}

@Bean(name = "modulesTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager modulesTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder)
        throws IOException {
    JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
    tm.setEntityManagerFactory(modulesEntityManagerFactory(builder).getObject());
    tm.setDataSource(modulesDataSource());
    return tm;
}

@Bean(name = "supplychainTransactionManager")
@Primary
public PlatformTransactionManager supplychainTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder)
        throws IOException {
    JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
    tm.setEntityManagerFactory(supplychainEntityManagerFactory(builder).getObject());
    tm.setDataSource(supplychainDataSource());
    return tm;
}
```

Adding both datasources, I can finally use both persistences!